# How to structure a neo4j graph db?

Tags: database, node.js, graph, neo4j

Hello i have problem designing a database based on neo4j. I want to be able to create relationships between nodes and get the node responsible for creating the relationship. 
An example that i come up with is:

User, Tag, Article.
User can tag article so...

[User]

[Tag] - [tags_article] -> [Article]

I want to be able to get all tags for article. That is easy with the relationship tags_article. But i want to get users that added tags to the article. I can't do this ...
Any ideas, how to associate the relationship with the node responsible for creating it?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
(User)-[:ADDED]->(Tag),
(Tag)-[:TAGS]->(Article)
```

And you could get what you're looking for with this:

```
MATCH (u)-[:ADDED]->(t)-[:TAGS]->(a)
WHERE a.name='whatever'
WITH t, u.name AS user
RETURN user, t.name
```

Comment: Also take a look at the hyperedges documentation.  
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/cypher-cookbook-hyperedges.html

Comment: In 2. you'd probably add labels for `:User, :Tag, :Article` and then create an index to speed up the lookup of articles by name `create index on :Article(name)`